# Two AJAX function calls - Best practice

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need the results of two `AJAX` calls, after which I will use the information retrieved to create a table.

I was curious... is nesting one`AJAX` call within the other and keeping the code for creating the table at the end of the 2nd `AJAX` call the proper way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest using jQuery's deferreds for this.

```
$ajax1 = $.ajax({
    url: '/page1'
});

$ajax2 = $.ajax({
    url: '/page2'
});

$.when($ajax1, $ajax2).done(function(data1, data2){
    // data1[0] is the result of the 1st AJAX call,
    // and data2[0] is the result of the 2nd
    // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
});
```

Both AJAX calls will be fired and `.done` will only run once *both* are finished.

Docs for `$.when`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Was just typing this out! agreed

Comment: This is great! I never knew this existed. +1

Comment: @megawac: Yeah, I see no reason to nest them, especially since they don't rely on each other or anything.

Comment: @Overcode: Yep, Deferreds are a fairly new thing in jQuery, they're nice :)

Comment: +1 I learned something today. This seems a very elegant way to synchronize non-dependent ajax calls.

Comment: @CAbbott: Yep!  I find it much cleaner than nesting them inside the callbacks.

Comment: @CAbbott i do say it below but IF you have the option to use a different promise library, i would recommend it, jquery has a "bad" implementation of the Common/Js promise spec (though it is better in jquery 1.8+) if you don't care, don't worry about it. But it is worth saying

Comment: @RocketHazmat jquery promises don't always resolve async (they should never resolve on the current event loop turn), which leads to inconsistencies. They also don't wrap and pass exceptions up the chain consistently. And up until 1.8+ .then() didn't return a new promise Most people may not notice the problem. but it can lead to annoying gotchas, and since this question was about "best practice" it felt worth mentioning. Here is a good blog on it generally speaking. http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks Rocket Hazmat! Didn't know this existed :)

Answer (score 0):

First promises are a good way to handle this, but the jquery promise implemenation is not great (it is not to spec) but it does work. If you can use a different library I recommend q.js otherwise here is how to do it in jquery

I usually use the `.then` to pipe the return value of the second ajax call and pass the promise around

```
function makeRequests(){
  var req1 = $.ajax("myurl");

  return req1.then(function(data){
     var req2 = $.ajax("second/one")


     return req2;
  })
}

makeRequest().done(function(dataFromReq2){
    //do work after both are done
})
```

if you need to do both requests in parallel then use `$.when(req1, req2)`

Comment: Your `return req2;` does nothing.  You can't return from the `.then` method.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thats just not true, you can return from it, it functions like older version of $.pipe() http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: Heh.  Didn't realize that.  I thought `then` would be asynchronous, like AJAX callbacks usually are.

Comment: So, how then do you get the results from *both* ajax calls in the `.done` function?

Comment: @RocketHazmat then() is async, you are getting a new promise. You don't get both you get what you return (or if you return a promise what that returns). if you need both responses at once, your answer of using $.when is definately more correct. I use the above when I need to chain ajax requests after each other and get a promise that resolves when the last ajax request is done req1 -> use resp for req2 -> done resolves with req2 response.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I didn't know you could that with `.then`, that's pretty cool :)